# CSS Font Bold - Inline

Tags: css

In CSS, how can I bold only the phone number so it will inline with the rest of the statement but the number is bold?

Instead of doing it in HTML as:

```
 <div class="bubbleContent">&#8250; Start posting jobs today–
<strong> 01234 567 890</strong></div>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">&#8250; Call me – 01234 567 890</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.bubbleContent  
{
font-size: 11px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. Unless you want to do some JavaScript which checks for a certain string (but I wouldn't advise it).

Comment: do you want it in php???

Comment: You cannot style content which doesn't have an HTML tag by definition. What you want is thus not possible.

Comment: You can't, not unless you wrap your number in a span.

Comment: I totally agree with @Xarcell, but for some reason folks down-voted my answer :)

Comment: The question is vague, but the most plausible interpretation is how to make some text bold without using HTML markup for it. The accepted answer does not address this question, so the question was apparently meant to ask something completely different. This makes this more or less a “not a real question”.

Comment: @Jukka agreeing with the close vote, the accepted answer is just not related to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<span>` as in example shown below:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="content">&#8250; Call me – <span class="highlight">01234 567 890</span></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div.content
{
font-size: 11px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 15px;
}

span.highlight
{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

You can also use `<div>` element with property `display:inline`, so it will be inline with the rest of the text.

Comment: This is a nonsensical answer - if he could put a span in there he should be inserting the strong tag instead right away.

Comment: This is the right way to implement the formatting: separate it from the HTML and put in CSS. Why are you down-voting my answer? Rgds,

Comment: His question explicitly states he doesn't want to use markup. And if he did, he should use the semantically correct strong tag, not a span. And if you use a class to style, don't name the class after the intended layout. Your answer is wrong on three counts.

Comment: What the author requires is to bold the phone only without any extra tags, which is basically impossible.

Comment: It well might be interpreted as a request for the answer on how to avoid formatting tags like <strong> to be embedded directly in HTML; so the right way is either to add <span> or <div> with property display set to inline, and put formatting in CSS. <span> will suffice, as suggested in my answer. Rgds,

Comment: In which universe is span a better alternative to strong for semantically declaring a small segment of inline content more important than its surrounding text? The only correct answer to the OP question is to use strong, which he doesn't want.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: it's just a concept of separation of programming concerns, which pertinent to this example, removes direct formatting specs (like <strong>, etc.) from the body of HTML and put it in CSS, resulting in the text to be better structured/clean, and all formatting residing in one place for better readability. This is a right way to implement it. So, I ask you again, why did you downvote my answer? Rgds,

Comment: You completely misunderstand the point of semantics - strong does not imply any kind of formatting like <b> used to do. Your answer received 3 downvotes, not just mine, because it doesn't answer the question and answers what was apparently intended by OP wrongly.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: My answer is actually accepted by the question originator. That's my intention to help that person, rather than getting involved in lengthy discussion with you, or any of your supporters. Rgds,

Comment: The point of the downvotes is to indicate to the originator he is accepting a wrong answer, and to you that it's wrong. Regretfully neither you nor he seem willing to take the hint.

Comment: I happen to agree with @AlexBell that, in this case, styling a span is a better solution, for at least one reason: if the OP chooses to emphasize the style in anything more than the default <strong> way, he need only tweak the CSS.  Or, if this is going into a CMS system, the users of the CMS system can be enabled to override the styling.  (Cavevat: I'm still newish to CSS so I may be overlooking something important.)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. You cannot style a piece of text in CSS without making it an element one way or another (unless it can be referred to as a pseudo-element, but this currently works for first letter and first line only).

There are many HTML elements that you could use (such as `strong`, `b`, `span`), but the point is that you need *some* element. You can use an element that is displayed in bold by default, or you can style it with CSS.

You could generate the element with JavaScript client-side, though. For this, you would need to specify the syntax of phone numbers to be recognized, making sure that only phone numbers will match it in the content that will be used.